# How to convert Linq query for joining 3 tables to Linq method and use Include

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have seen a few posts that are similar but I haven't been able to figure out how to solve my problem. I have three tables in an ASP.NET Core project. There is a `one-to-many` relationship on my Prescriptions and Prescribers tables and `one-to-many` relationship on my Prescribers and Marketers tables. I want to query the Prescriptions table and fetch the foreign key `PrescriberId`, then query Prescribers table and fetch the foreign key `MarketerId` and return the `MarketerId`. So far I have this linq

```
'var presciber = from p in _context.Prescriptions
                 join f in _context.Prescribers on p.PrescriberId equals f.Id
                 join m in _context.Marketers on f.MarketerId equals m.Id
                 where p.FolderStatusId == 3
                 select new { m.Id };
```

I want to be able to use `.Include` so I can include other data from Marketers table, so instead of displaying `MarketerId`, I can display Marketer `Name` and not get null in the view. So I want to convert this query into a method, I have tried this

```
var prescriber = _context.Prescriptions
    .Join(_context.Prescribers,
    p => p.PrescriberId,
    f => f.Id,
    (p, f) => new { Prescriptions = p, Prescribers = f })
    .Join(_Context.Marketers,
    f => f.Prescribers.MarketerId,
    m => m.Id,
    (f, m) => new { Prescribers = f, Marketers = m })
    .Where(d => d.FolderStatusId == 3);//This line gets the error
```

On the `Where` clause I get the error

```
<anonmyous type: <anonymous type:Prescription Prescriptions, Prescriber Prescribers> Prescribers, Marketer Marketers> does not contain a definition for FolderStatusId
```

Here are my classes

```
public class Prescriptions {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int FolderStatusId {get;set;}
  public int PrescriberId { get; set; }
  public string Medication { get; set; }
  public virtual Prescriber Prescriber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Prescribers class

```
public class Prescriber {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MarketerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Marketer Marketer {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Prescription> Prescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Marketer class

```
public class Marketer {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Prescriber> Prescribers { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how can I correct this Linq method and also where do I add the `.Include`?

Comment: Can you please add your entity definitions.

Comment: `Include` is for navigation properties not for other colunns, for that you'd just add all the column you want in the select.  Speaking of navigation properties I'd suggest looking into using them instead of Joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: I added the model classes and I will look into the navigation

Comment: You have navigation properties, so why do you `join`?

Comment: I'm open to learning any better solutions. I used `join` because I thought that was the way to go but I'm not necessarily restricted to only `join`

Comment: Also Prescriptions table does not have a navigation property Marketers and I need to reference specific data from the marketers table pending the results of the query

Comment: Change last line to... `.Where(d => d.Prescribers.Prescriptions.FolderStatusId == 3);`

Comment: I see now that this works and I don't need an include because `select { m.Id };`. I can just specify any properties that I will need to use.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use identifiers that would mean anything to the reader. That would have helped you to see the cause of the problem:

```
var result = _context.Prescriptions
.Join(_context.Prescribers,
prescription => prescription.PrescriberId,
prescriber => prescriber.Id,
(prescription, prescriber) => new
{ 
    Prescription = prescription,
    Prescriber = prescriber,
})
// End of first join

.Join(_Context.Marketers,
firstJoinResult => firstJoinResult.Prescriber.MarketerId,
marketer => marketer.Id,

(firstJoinResult, marketer) => new
{
    Prescription = prescription,
    Prescriber = prescriber,
    Marketer = marketer,
})
// end of second join

.Where(secondJoinResult => secondJoinResult.FolderStatusId == 3);
//This line gets the error
```

Your second join result, does not have a property FolderStatusId. In your original code, you used identifier `d` to refer to the second join result. Only `Prescriptions` have a `FolderStatusId`. So your `Where` should be like:

```
.Where(secondJoinResult => secondJoinResult.Prescription.FolderStatusId == 3);
```

### There's room for improvement

#### Use Where before the joins

If you use the Where before you start joining, a lot of Prescriptions don't have to be joined at all:

```
var result = _context.Prescriptions
    .Where(prescription => prescription.FolderStatusId == 3);
    .Join(_context.Prescribers,
        prescription => prescription.PrescriberId,
        prescriber => prescriber.Id,
        ... // etc
```

#### Select only the properties that you plan to use

So a `Marketer` has zero or more `Prescribers`, and every `Prescriber` has zero or more `Prescriptions`, like you said: one-to-many relationships.

Every Prescription of Marketer [14] has a foreign key `MarketerId` with a value 14. If Marketer [14] has 1000 Prescriptions, then you would transfer 1000 times the combination of Marketer [14] with one of the Prescriptions with MarketerId [14].

Apart from the fact that you would transfer 1000 times the same Marketer data, you would also transfer the same value of `Prescription.MarketerId`, of which you already know the value: it has value [14]. What a waste of processing power!

Solution: select only the properties that you plan to use:

```
    var result = _context.Prescriptions
    .Where(prescription => prescription.FolderStatusId == 3);
    .Join(_context.Prescribers,
        prescription => prescription.PrescriberId,
        prescriber => prescriber.Id,
        ... // etc
        (firstJoinResult, marketer) => new
        {
            Marketer = new
            {
                // Select only the Marketer properties that you plan to use
                Id = marketer.Id,
                Name = markter.Name,
                ...
            }

            Subscriber = new
            {
                // Again: only the properties that you plan to use:
                Id = firstJoinResult.Subscriber.Id,
                Name = markter.Name,

                // No need for this, you  know the value:
                // MarketerId = firstJoinResult.Subscriber.MarketerId,
            },

            Prescription = new { ... },
       });
```

> In Entity framework always use Select to query data and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to change the included data.

The reason is, that entity framework can only update items that are fetched completely.

#### Consider a GroupJoin

I already mentioned in the previous chapter: the same values of Marketer [14] will be transferred many times.

Whenever you want Items with their subitems, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, and Marketers with their Prescribers, consider a GroupJoin instead of a Join.

```
var result = _context.Marketers
    .GroupJoin(_context.Prescribers,
        marketer => marketer.Id,
        prescriber => prescriber.MarketerId,

        // parameter ResultSelector:
        // get all Marketers with their prescribers to make one new
        (marketer, prescribersOfThisMarketer) => new
        {
            Id = marketer.Id,
            Name = marketer.Name,
            ...

            Prescribers = prescribersOfThisPrescription.GroupJoin(
                _context.Prescriptions.Where(prescription => prescription.FolderStatusId == 3),
                prescriber => prescriber.Id,
                prescription => prescription.PrescriberId,

                // from every prescriber with all its prescriptions, make one new
                (prescriber, prescriptionsOfThisPrescriber) => new
                {
                    Id = prescriber.Id,
                    Name = prescriber.Name,
                    ...

                    Prescriptions = prescriptionsOfThisPrescriber.Select(presription => new
                    {
                         Id = prescription.Id,
                         ...
                    })
                    .ToList(),
                })
                .ToList(),
        });
```

So Instead of

```
Marketer  Subscriber
   A          10
   A          11
   B          20
   A          28
   C          12
   B          13
```

You get:

- Marketer A with his Subscribers 10, 11, 28
- Marketer B with his Subscriber 20, 13
- Marketer C with his Subscriber 12
- Marketer D without any Subscribers

This usually looks more like you would want your result.

**Note: GroupJoin will also return items that have no subitems!**, like Marketers without any Subscribers. Usually you want this, but if you don't want them, use a Where to filter them out:

```
.Where(marketer => marketer.Subscribers.Any());
```

#### The most revolutional: use the ICollection!

Some people told me that EF-core does not support this. I know that full entity framework certainly does: use the ICollections instead of a group-join.

**Requirement** Give me (some properties of) all Marketers, each with (some properties of all) his Prescribers, each with his Prescriptions.

```
var marketers = dbContext.Marketers.Select(marketer => new
{
    Id = marketer.Id,
    Name = marketer.Name,
    ...

    Prescribers = marketer.Prescribers.Select(prescriber => new
    {
        Id = prescriber.Id,
        Name = prescriber.Name,
        ...

        Prescriptions = prescriber.Prescriptions
            .Where(prescription => prescription.FolderStatusId == 3)
            .Select(prescription => new
            {
                 Id = prescription.Id,
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

This feels way more naturally than a (Group-)Join. Entity framework knows the relations between the tables and translate it into the correct (Group-)Join.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Much more than I was expecting.